# Variance of the estimators in Linear Model with manual formulae in R

Tags: r, regression, variance, linear

I'm working on a linear model like:

[image]

I'm applying the formulae to the data to calculate the estimators of a and b using R.
First I got some data like:

```
x <- c(10,11,23,24)
y <- c(4,2,7,8)
```

Then I applied the `lm()` to have the results:

```
model <- lm(y~x)          # the model

coefficients(model)       # the coefficients
(Intercept)           x 
 -0.5500000   0.3411765 

sqrt(diag(vcov(model)))   # the s.e.
(Intercept)           x 
 1.69932945  0.09333313
```

So I decided to calculate manually the coefficients and the s.e. I used this formulae for the coefficients:

[image]

[image]

And in R I did something like:

```
bHat <- cov(x,y)/var(x)
aHat <- mean(y)-(cov(x,y)/var(x))*mean(x)

bHat
[1] 0.3411765
aHat
[1] -0.55
```

Then I calculate the s.e.. I used those formulae:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And

[image]

[image]

So I tried those formulae in R.

```
se.bHat <- sqrt(sigma/sum((x-(mean(x)))^2)) 
se.bHat
[1] 0.211205

 se.aHat <- sqrt((sigma/4)*  (1+4*mean(x)^2)/sum((x-(mean(x)))^2))
 se.aHat
 [1] 3.590497
```

But the result is not equal to the `lm()` output.
Am I using the wrong formulae in the theory or am I applying them wrongly?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I've tried as suggested this as the formula `σ^2 = 1/(n-p) Sum(w[i] R[i]^2)` with `help(summary.lm)`:

```
sigma <- (1/(4-2))*sum(residuals(model)^2)
se.bHat <- sqrt(sigma/sum((x-(mean(x)))^2))
se.bHat
[1] 0.09333313
```

And the result is not ok. I'm going to try also with the intercept.

Comment: How do you calculate `sigma`? Note that it is squared in the formula. Also, your code for `se.aHat` doesn't match the formula you provide.

Comment: The formula of the sigma is after the var(b) formula, however is var(y) (but I can be wrong).  Edited the formula. The theory formula are correct in your opinion or wrong?

Comment: Please add all code you used to the question.

Comment: I've added it: you can find the formula for the lm() part and also for the manual part. For the not matching formula I've edited it adding the missing +1 if it was the problem. If you need something more specific, ask without problems.

Comment: Where did you get the formula for sigma? It's not correct. See `help("summary.lm")` (under "Value") for the correct definition.

Comment: It works if I avoid the w[i] for the coefficient. Are them the weights? Is it correct I'm avoiding them? Added the edit.

Comment: Unweighted regression is the same as all weights equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I used the wrong formula for sigma square.
using:

```
help("summary.lm")
```

As suggested by Roland (see comments below), you can find that the right formula is as stated by R guide:

the square root of the estimated variance of the random error

σ^2 = 1/(n-p) Sum(w[i] R[i]^2)

where R[i] is the i-th residual, residuals[i].

So

[image]

Answer (score 1):

due to the fact, that i can´t give a comment:

i know  a different formula for the s.e of a:

[image]

I have it from the book: Applied Regression Analysis, Linear Models, and Related Methods by John Fox (1997).

Using it in R: (maybe a too many brackets :D)

```
> (se.aHat <- ((sigma*sum(x^2))/(n*(sum((x-mean(x))^2)))))
[1] 2.887721
> sqrt(se.aHat)
[1] 1.699329
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that I used a wrong formula for sigma square, a bit different from mine. Using the command help("summary.lm") as suggest by Roland, I've found that the right formula is σ^2 = 1/(n-p) Sum(w[i] R[i]^2). Your formula is however correct, it gives the same result of mine.

Comment: perfect! Maybe you should edit it again and state it as solved :). Greetings from germany!